# Applying multiple test correction - is there anything I can do?

Tags: r, regression, false-discovery-rate

This is more a postmortem question in the form of a particular experiment, so unfortunately I can't go back and change the experimental design.

**Data**
 - I have Human Methylation data, ~400K probes (rows), ~200 Samples (columns). The samples are split into 3 categories (diseases).

**Parameter of Interest**
- I have an integer value of 1:50 that each sample is assigned.

**The Test**
- I'm testing for probes that correlate with the parameter of interest, for a particular disease group. I've used the Limma package in R to do this. (Code example below).

**The Problem**
Nothing is surviving multiple test correction. There are two things that would help in this situation, add more samples (can't do that), or reduce the number of probes (no rationale for that). Are there any other options I have?? (I've tried the different forms of P value adjustment in Limma and nothing passes in all of them). The reason I ask is that if I check probes with a low P value (< 0.0001), their correlations look tight and convincing.

#### Code

```
lvcm.design <- model.matrix(~as.numeric(pData(lvcm.in)$Variable))
lvcm.fit    <- lmFit(minfi::getM(lvcm.in), lvcm.design)
lvcm.fit2   <- eBayes(lvcm.fit)
topTable(fit           = lvcm.fit2,
         coef          = 2,
         p.value       = 0.05,
         number        = Inf,
         adjust.method = "BH",
         sort.by       = "P")
```

Comment: You do have to consider the possibility that none of the probes is related to your "parameter of interest." Even at p = 0.0001, there would be 1 case in 10,000 called a false positive, so you might expect about 40 such false positives in your 400K probes. Those might individually look "convincing" but might just represent the luck of the draw.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree. I guess I just have to accept that these tests are underpowered in terms of sample size. There is one disease state where it yields 12 probes that pass FDR correction - The disease state with the most samples.

Comment: Before you give up on this, consider re-evaluating the scaling of your "parameter of interest," which seems to be treated as a numeric variable running from 1 to 50. Your model implicitly assumes that averages in this linear scale are the best behaved for statistical testing. A square-root, log, or some other scaling of that variable might improve performance. Providing more information on your "parameter of interest" might lead to suggestions about ways to proceed.

Comment: The parameter of Interest is Age - I have tried log2, log10 and sqrt, all of which don't really have an impact. Ultimately I'm relatively sure this is a power issue more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially try the [knockoff filter](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/FDR_regression.pdf) to control the FDR. There is a [package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knockoff/index.html) for it.

Here are [some slides](http://www.iip.ist.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/mlss15/doku.php?id=schedule#topics_in_selective_inference) by Emmanuel Candes to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Because your data are naturally stratified into three disease, I suggest you look into Lei Sun et al's [stratified FDR](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/craiu/Papers/strat-FDR.pdf) method. Basically all three diseases are corrected separately, assuming different $\pi_0$ or proportion of null hypothesis. The paper does a very good job explaining the method, but if you have any questions don't hesitate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I should have made it clear in my code though, I'm subsetting the data for the given disease state to do each test

Comment: Ah, my apologies. It's early and I haven't had my coffee. In that case, the paper should still be of some help. Other than that, if you don't have any significant hits (which could just be the truth of the model), you could look into reporting the $q$-values as described in John Storey's [qvalue](https://github.com/jdstorey/qvalue) package and associated paper.In that way the reader could make whatever conclusions they so wished based on the $q$-value.

Comment: Thanks for the qvalue package suggestion - I think I just have to accept that this test in underpowered!

Answer (score 0):

If your variable has different conditions, consider building the model matrix differently, by blocking each group as a variable something like this:

```
         Group1 | Group2 | Group3
Sample_1    1   |    0   |   0
Sample_2    1   |    0   |   0
Sample_3    0   |    1   |   0
Sample_4    0   |    1   |   0
Sample_5    0   |    0   |   1
Sample_6    0   |    0   |   1
```

This way your model has more power, and can discriminate better between groups of your variable of interest